# proof: upper bound error of approximating a number with only $n$ decimals precision

Tags: rounding-error, truncation-error

Suppose you have a real number $A$ and approximate it by only $n$ decimal places. Call this number $a$. proof that the upper bound of absolute error of this approximation $|A-a| \le 5 \times 10^{-(n+1)}$.

Can anyone help me to solve this theorem? I thought that i can use induction technique but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What is the distance between two neighboring numbers with $n$ decimal places?  $A$ is no more than half that from the nearest one.

Comment: Thanks, It's intuitive. But can you provide a mathematical proof?

Comment: I believe this is a proof.  You could add some details, starting with justifying the distance statement from the fact that a number with $n$ decimals is an integer times $10^{-n}$.  The minimum spacing of integers of $1$ translates to the spacing of the decimals.  Then assume your number is more than $5\cdot 10^{n+1}$ from one end of the interval, show that it is less than that from the other end.